# Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть программа которую пытаюсь переписать с помощью методов класса `Array` на C#. Через метод `Array.FindAll`.

Первый кусок кода, где нужно сосчитать сумму положительных элементов в первой половине массива, считается только если убрать второй, где нужно сосчитать сумму отрицательных элементов во второй половине. Если же все вместе пытаюсь сделать, то получается ошибка "индекс находился вне границ массива". Помогите пожалуйста исправить.

Вот сама задача:

Сосчитать сумму положительных элементов в первой половине массива, сумму отрицательных элементов во второй половине массива.

```cs
namespace _2_cs_l3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int n; //= Convert.ToInt16(textBox1.Text);
            int[] A = new int[100];
            int Summa1, Summa2;
            int c = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            string[] sNums = textBox2.Text.Split(',');
            if (c > sNums.Length)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Длина массива не соответсвует введенному!");
                return;
            }
            int[] nums = new int[c];
            for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
            {
                nums[i] = int.Parse(sNums[i]);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(nums[i] + "\t");
                listBox1.Items.Add("\n");
            }
            Summa1 = 0; Summa2 = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < c/2; i++)
            {
                int[] b = Array.FindAll(nums, x => x > 0);
                Summa1 += b[i];
            }
            listBox1.Items.Add("Сумма положительных элементов в первой полоине массива: ");
            listBox1.Items.Add(Summa1 + "\t");

            for (int i = c/2; i < c; i++)
            {
                int [] k = Array.FindAll(nums, x => x < 0);
                Summa2 += k[i];
            }
            listBox1.Items.Add("Сумма отрицательных элементов во второй полоине массива: ");
            listBox1.Items.Add(Summa2 + "\t");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вы пишите в процедурном стиле, так хоть делите алгоритм, на отдельные процедуры(методы). Получить данные - первый метод, получить сумму положительных - второй метод, получить сумму отрицательных - третий метод. Разбивка на отдельные методы помогает читать и понимать код, а самое главное отлаживать код и находить ошибки.

Comment: @Bulson А каким образом делить нужно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример массива

```
var array = new[] { -1, 3, -1, 6, -6, 1, -3, 1 };
```

Сумма положительных в первой половине

```
var summaPos = array.Take(array.Length / 2).Where(x => x > 0).Sum();
```

Сумма отрицательных во второй

```
var summaNeg = array.Skip(array.Length / 2).Where(x => x < 0).Sum();
```

Проверка

```
Console.WriteLine($"{summaPos} / {summaNeg}");
```

Вывод

```
9 / -9
```

С использованием методов Array

```
var array = new[] { -1, 3, -1, 6, -6, 1, -3, 1 };

int[] firstHalf = new int[array.Length/2];
int[] secondHalf= new int[array.Length - array.Length/2]; 

Array.Copy(array, firstHalf, array.Length/2);
Array.Copy(array, array.Length/2, secondHalf, 0, array.Length - array.Length/2);

var summaPos = Array.FindAll(firstHalf, x=>x>0).Sum();
var summaNeg  = Array.FindAll(secondHalf, x=>x<0).Sum();

Console.WriteLine($"{summaPos} / {summaNeg}");
```

Вывод

```
9 / -9
```

Comment: Спасибо, но тут же нет методов класса array?

Comment: @Zhenyadze Обновил

Comment: Спасибо огромное.